# A recursive code approach to the sequence alignment

Tags: recursion, bioinformatics

I am looking for a recursive code for the sequence alignment problem.  After a search I found the Needleman Wunsch algorithm, but the building of the matrix table was implemented with two for loops, other than that I could not find any recursive code that does the trick in a normal time.  Any ideas for a recursive code implementation? 
Thanks!

Comment: You write the code. We help when you get stuck

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask people for complete code that solves a problem. We can help you debug the code you have, though. (As a note: I've never seen a recursive implementation of sequence alignment, since the iterative DP solution is more space-efficient, significantly faster, and significantly cleaner.)

Comment: I am not looking for a whole code, I am just looking for an idea!

Answer (score 4):

## Recursive implementation with caching

Indexing gets a little messy as I use length of strings in 0-based arrays and as
bound. But it is nice how closely this resembles the recurrence. 
Allocating stack frames in a quadratic alg
is prob not a good idea however with a VM that doesn't support tail calls
and a implementation that isn't tail recurse.

**Running Time:** O(n*m)

```
public static int solveWithCache(String n, String m) {
  String paddedN = " " + n; //makes some indexing easier if we pad.
  String paddedM = " " + m;

  int[][] cache = new int[paddedN.length()][paddedM.length()];

  for(int[] row : cache)
    Arrays.fill(row, Integer.MIN_VALUE);

  return solveWithCacheCompute(paddedN, paddedM, paddedN.length()-1, paddedM.length()-1, cache);
}

private static int solveWithCacheCompute(String n, String m, int i, int j, int[][] cache) {
  if(i == 0 && j == 0) return 0;
  if(cache[i][j] != Integer.MIN_VALUE) return cache[i][j];
  if(i == 0) return (j) * gapPenalty;
  if(j == 0) return (i) * gapPenalty;

  int matchScore = (n.charAt(i) == m.charAt(j)) ? matchBenefit : mismatchPenalty;

  int leaveIt = solveWithCacheHelper(n, m, i-1, j-1, cache) + matchScore;
  int addGapN = solveWithCacheHelper(n, m, i-1, j, cache) + gapPenalty;
  int addGapM = solveWithCacheHelper(n, m, i, j-1, cache) + gapPenalty;

  return Math.max(leaveIt, Math.max(addGapN, addGapM));
}
```

## Iterative Implementation

*(To easily compare)* 
Typical DP style. Watch those indexes though; they be tricky.

```
public static int solve(String n, String m) {
  int nlen = n.length();
  int mlen = m.length();
  int[][] maxAlign = new int[nlen + 1][mlen + 1];

  for(int q = 0; q <= nlen; q++) 
    maxAlign[q][0] = q * gapPenalty;

  for(int r = 0; r <= mlen; r++) 
    maxAlign[0][r] = r * gapPenalty;

  for(int i = 1; i <= nlen; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= mlen; j++) {
        int matchScore = (n.charAt(i-1) == m.charAt(j-1)) ? matchBenefit : mismatchPenalty;

        int leaveIt = maxAlign[i-1][j-1] + matchScore;
        int addGapN = maxAlign[i-1][j] + gapPenalty;
        int addGapM = maxAlign[i][j-1] + gapPenalty;

        maxAlign[i][j] = Math.max(leaveIt, Math.max(addGapN, addGapM));
    }
  }

  return maxAlign[nlen][mlen];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want a recursive algorithm?

It looks like the sequence alignment problem can be solved via dynamic programming - this is what the Needleman Wunsch algorithm is doing. From the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm) there is a recurrence given for solving the problem. This **is** one recursive solution. However, this recursive solution performs the same sub-problem calculation over and over. The dynamic programming solution subverts by solving the problem bottom-up and storing computations for future look-up (memoization) via the two for loops.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how the needleman wunsch is a recursive solution like you stated.  There is no recursive call in the code, could you explain how it is recursive?

Comment: The recurrence given in the Wikipedia article is

F{i,j} = max(F{i-1,j-1} + S(A{i}, B{j}), F{i,j-1} + d, F{i-1,j} + d) 

This recursive solution is extremely slow because it re-computes the same thing over and over again. It's also a top-down approach. Instead, they compute all F{i,j} values bottom up (e.g., starting with F{0,0} via the for loops.

If you're not familiar with dynamic programming, I suggest you read up on it - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming. All dynamic programming problems are inherently recursive.